# Haxe JS compiler removes one attribute from the source

Tags: javascript, class, compilation, attributes, haxe

I have a class named `ServerProxy` with three attributes in it. Two of them are public (`getSmiliesCompleteSignal` and `getMessagesCompleteSignal`), and the third one is private (`_url`).

When I compile my project, the compiler does not display errors, it even compiles good (I can see my modifications in the result source), but it removes one attribute from my class: `getMessagesCompleteSignal`. Never seen it before.

Here is the class:

```
package net;

import js.Browser;
import entity.Message.MessageData;
import haxe.Json;
import js.html.XMLHttpRequest;
import entity.Smiley.SmileyData;
import msignal.Signal;

class ServerProxy
{
    public var getSmiliesCompleteSignal:Signal1<Array<SmileyData>>;
    public var getMessagesCompleteSignal:Signal1<Array<MessageData>>;

    private var _url:String;

    public function new():Void
    {
        _url = untyped Browser.window.serverUrl;
        getSmiliesCompleteSignal = new Signal1<Array<SmileyData>>();
    }

    public function getSmilies():Void
    {
        sendRequest(ServerAction.GetSmilies, getSmiliesCompleteSignal, ServerMethod.GET);
    }

    public function getMessages():Void
    {
        sendRequest(ServerAction.GetMessages, getMessagesCompleteSignal, ServerMethod.GET);
    }

    public function sendRequest(action:ServerAction, completeSignal:Signal1<Array<Dynamic>>, method:ServerMethod, ?sentData:String):Void
    {
        var url = _url + action;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data:Dynamic) {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                completeSignal.dispatch(cast Json.parse(data.srcElement.responseText));
            }
        };

        xhr.open(cast method, url);
        xhr.send(sentData);
    }
}

@:enum
abstract ServerAction(String) {
    var GetSmilies = 'smiley/view';
    var GetMessages = 'message/view';
}

@:enum
abstract ServerMethod(String) {
    var GET = 'GET';
    var POST = 'POST';
}
```

And here is the compiled source:

```
var net_ServerProxy = function() {
    this._url = window.serverUrl;
    this.getSmiliesCompleteSignal = new msignal_Signal1();
};
net_ServerProxy.__name__ = true;
net_ServerProxy.prototype = {
    getSmilies: function() {
        this.sendRequest("smiley/view",this.getSmiliesCompleteSignal,"GET");
    }
    ,getMessages: function() {
        this.sendRequest("message/view",this.getMessagesCompleteSignal,"GET");
    }
    ,sendRequest: function(action,completeSignal,method,sentData) {
        var url = this._url + action;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4) completeSignal.dispatch(JSON.parse(data.srcElement.responseText));
        };
        xhr.open(method,url);
        xhr.send(sentData);
    }
    ,__class__: net_ServerProxy
};
```

As you can see, this attribute disappeared. And of course, it causes a fatal error in the execution.

Comment: Are you using dce? What happens if you add `-dce no` / `-D no-opt` / `-D no-simplify`? It may be compiler bug. if you can reduce it to a minimal example that don't use any haxelib, we can go to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor you forgot to initialize your property getMessagesCompleteSignal

```
public function new():Void
{
    _url = untyped Browser.window.serverUrl;
    getSmiliesCompleteSignal = new Signal1<Array<SmileyData>>();
    getMessagesCompleteSignal = new Signal1<Array<MessageData>>(); // This one
}
```